# importmulti native segwit address to fetch utxos of p2wpkh native segwit address

Tags: bitcoind, segregated-witness, importaddress, importmulti

I must fetch utxos for a native segwit address from the local Bitcoin node.
First I wanted to import the segwit address. However, it fails.

How can I import a native segwit address? I'm using latest `bitcoind` version `240001`

```bash
# bitcoin-cli -testnet importmulti '[{"scriptPubKey": {"address": "bc1qerwt7v72j0w70ezw09keaqzcsss......."}, "timestamp": "now"}]'
error code: -4
error message:
Only legacy wallets are supported by this command
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For modern "descriptor" wallets, you need to convert whatever you want to import to the [output descriptor language](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md), and import that using the `importdescriptors` RPC.

For an individual address, the descriptor is just `addr(ADDR)`, where `ADDR` is the address you want to import. The `importdescriptors` RPC requires descriptors to have a checksum, of the form `#CHECK`, where `CHECK` is the checksum. You can compute the necessary checksum using the `getdescriptorinfo` RPC.

Comment: bitcoin-cli -testnet  importDescriptors '[{"desc": "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7....)", "timestamp": "now"}]' still fails. Error message is Method not found. Bitcoin Core RPC client version v24.0.1

Comment: Do not capitalize the D in importdescriptors.

Comment: bitcoin-cli -testnet  importdescriptors '[{"desc": "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)", "checksum": "h8rwjq0n", "timestamp": "now"}]'

[
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -5,
      "message": "Missing checksum"
    }
  }
]

Comment: I told you you need to compute and add the checksum, for example using `getdescriptorinfo`.

Comment: Got it. Changed it to bitcoin-cli -testnet - importdescriptors '[{"desc": "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)#h8rwjq0n", "timestamp": "now"}]'

Comment: The error message has changed to

  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "code": -4,
      "message": "Cannot import descriptor without private keys to a wallet with private keys enabled"
    }
  }
]

Comment: You'll need to create a wallet for watching, without private keys, using the `createwallet` RPC, and import into that.

Comment: Thank you! I'm able to import it into wallet test4. Then I deposited some testnet bitcoin into it. Should I supposed to see it with the `bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=test4 listunspent `

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Pieter I'm able to import and segwit address into a wallet.

- Created a wallet without private keys.

```bash
~$ bitcoin-cli -testnet createwallet test4 true
{
  "name": "test4",
  "warning": ""
}
```

- Get descriptor info to obtain hash

```
~$ bitcoin-cli -testnet getdescriptorinfo "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)"
{
 "descriptor": "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)#h8rwjq0n",
 "checksum": "h8rwjq0n",
 "isrange": false,
 "issolvable": false,
 "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

- Imported the address

```bash
~$ bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=test4 importdescriptors '[{"desc": "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)#h8rwjq0n", "timestamp": "now"}]'
[
  {
    "success": true
  }
]
```

After a couple of minutes, the testnet bitcoins I've sent to the address appeared in the wallet.

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=test4 listunspent 
[
  {
    "txid": "c50321fa5a86a281882283b507f33529682158998d32bb335c125ed2e2b6e614",
    "vout": 0,
    "address": "tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza",
    "label": "",
    "scriptPubKey": "001435cd4402887765c57eef09a61f0033ae8f4c3990",
    "amount": 0.00001000,
    "confirmations": 1,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": false,
    "parent_descs": [
      "addr(tb1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvsfuejza)#h8rwjq0n"
    ],
    "safe": true
  }
]
```